# What is the difference between boost::bind and boost::lambda::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-lambda

I can see that there are two different bind libraries for Boost, one "standalone", that can be used by including `boost/bind.hpp`, and another by including `boost/lambda/bind.hpp`. What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the explanation here: http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/lambda/s08.html#id2143701

They have overlapping functionality but with semantic differences, they can't be used interleaved.